# Finding occurrences of a specific integer

Tags: python, integer

I keep getting a keyerror on line 9 and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

This is my code

```
numbers = (input("Enter numbers separated by spaces > "))
alist = []
alist = numbers.split()
count = {}
for word in alist:
    if word not in alist:
        (count[word]) = 1
    else:
        (count[word]) = (count[word]) + 1
print(count)
for k,v in count.item():
    if v == 1:
        print(k, "occurs", v, "time")
    else:
        print(k, "occurs", v, "times")
```

Comment: (you don't need to put everything in parenthesis)

Comment: By the way, you could use `count = collections.Counter(alist)` and omit the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word not in alist` is always false because the for loop iterate over `alist`.

Replace following line:

```
if word not in alist:
```

with

```
if word not in count:
```

BTW, you don't need the parentheses around `count[word]`.

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed. I feel so ditzy when it's just one dumb mistake I make, haha. You are a lifesaver.

Comment: Thank you both. I have to wait 8 minutes to hit the check mark thing, I will once I can.

Comment: @aneroid, What do you mean for **that**?

Comment: @falsetru, here the 'that' is just grammar. deleted to clarify here: Perhaps add to your answer... Since the if-clause is false, the expression `count[word] + 1` in else throws the error since the key `word` doesn't exist in the `count` dict when evaluated.